# Scala programatic variable creation

Tags: scala

I am very new to Scala. I would like to assign a string as variable name:

```
val names = Vector("a","b","c")
for (name <~ names){
 val <xyz> = "test"
}
```

I would like to have three variables assigned as:

```
a: String = test
b: String = test
c: String = test
```

How do I code  to get this result?

Answer (score 1):

I first misunderstood your question.

```
val map = (for (name <- names) yield (name -> "test")).toMap
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a -> test, b -> test, c -> test)
```

This is called a Map, and it is used like that:

```
scala> map.get ("b")
res9: Option[String] = Some(test)

scala> map.get ("f")
res10: Option[String] = None
```

If you just search for a short form to initialize 3 variables, you can do:

```
val (a, b, c) = ("test", "test", "test")
a: String = test
b: String = test
c: String = test
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [user unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312172/user-unknown) answer, you can use pattern matching over `Vector`, although it is far from elegant if you just want to create three variables with the same value. As user unknown pointed out, you can pattern match over a tuple: `val (a, b, c) = ("test", "test", "test")`

```
val namesList = List("a", "b", "c")

val a :: b :: c :: Nil = for {
  name <- namesList
} yield "test"

// a: String = test
// b: String = test
// c: String = test

val namesVector = Vector("a", "b", "c")

val d +: e +: f +: Vector() = for {
  name <- namesVector
} yield "test"

// a: String = test
// b: String = test
// c: String = test
```

Answer (score 1):

Hm... There is a way to use **Scala Macro** with [Scala meta](http://scalameta.org/) to achieve this. Example:

```
object VarrApp extends App {
  // create a Varr annotation, this in the compile time, will automatically expand the names Vector and generate these variables
  @Varr
  val names = Vector("a", "b", "c")
  println(a) // test
  println(b) // test
  println(c) // test
}
```

to achieve this:

1.create a submodule for macros, project structure like:

```
   project:
       macros-submodule/src/main/scala/Varr.scala
       src/main/scala/VarrApp.scala
```

2.add **Scala meta dependency**, like the document, add the **paradise** compiler plugin, like:

```
addCompilerPlugin(
  "org.scalameta" % "paradise" % "3.0.0-M7" cross CrossVersion.full),
```

and enable **macroparadise** in **scalacOptions**, like:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Xplugin-require:macroparadise")
```

3.Implement `Varr` annotation, like:

```
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
import scala.meta._

class Varr extends StaticAnnotation {
  inline def apply(defn: Any): Any = meta {
    defn match {
      case q"val $name = Vector(..$paramss)" => {
        val stats = paramss.map {
          case i: Lit =>
            s"""val ${i.value} = "test"""".parse[Stat].get
        }
        q"""
            ..$stats
         """
      }
      case _ => abort("illegal stats")
    }
  }
}
```